# How do I use variable values within a function in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
let libraryResponse;

  function callBack(response) {
    const libraryLibraryResponse = response;
    libraryResponse = libraryLibraryResponse;
    //console.log('libraryLibraryResponse ', libraryLibraryResponse);
    //console.log('libraryResponse ', libraryResponse);

    //return libraryLibraryResponse;
  }
return libraryResponse;
```

This is my code from a function that goes to get information and save in the variables "libraryResponse" and "libraryLibraryResponse".
What I need is to be able to return the value of these variables that are within the function. Since the file is only functions.js.

If it was a component file, I could easily do it with useState, but in this case I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an object literal contain both values.

```
  function callBack(response) {

    const libraryLibraryResponse = response;
    libraryResponse = libraryLibraryResponse;
    
    // Short cut for {foo: libraryResponse, bar: libraryLibraryResponse};
    return {libraryResponse, libraryLibraryResponse};
  }

const cbResult = callBack(resp);

console.log('libraryResponse ', cbResult.libraryResponse);
console.log('libraryLibraryResponse ', cbResult.libraryLibraryResponse);
```

Comment: that function is used to fetch information from an image in another function. when doing "const cbResult = callBack(resp);" 
you fetch the initial content that is undefined and only then fetch the image information for the variables, so the final result is undefined as well.
I'm going to put the whole code in!

Answer (score 0):

**Thi is whole code**

```
export async function launchImageLibrary() {
let libraryResponse;

function callBack(response) {
  const libraryLibraryResponse = response;
  libraryResponse = libraryLibraryResponse;
  console.log('image library callback: ', libraryResponse);

  // Short cut for {foo: libraryResponse, bar: libraryLibraryResponse};
  return libraryResponse;
}

const cbResult = callBack(resp);
console.log('cbResult ', cbResult);

try {
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
  );
  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
  let options = {
    storageOptions: {
      skipBackup: true,
      path: 'images',
    },
  };

  ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
    if (response.didCancel) {
      console.log('User cancelled image picker');
    } else if (response.error) {
      console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
    } else if (response.customButton) {
      console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      alert(response.customButton);
    } else {
      libraryResponse = {
        uri: response.assets[0].uri,
        fileName: response.assets[0].fileName,
        type: response.assets[0].type,
      };

      callBack(libraryResponse);
    }
  });
} else {
  console.log('Library permission denied');
}
} catch (err) {
 console.log(err);
}

return rResult;
```

}

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This code is for a function that asks the user for permissions to access the image gallery and upload a photo.
At the end of the function you must return the name, type, and uri of the chosen image, and then be sent to the API for this data.
My difficulty is in returning this image data, which is stored in the "libraryResponse" within the function that lies within the try ... Catch

Answer (score 0):

In case you wanna store the value outside of the launchImageLibrary you could something like:

```
…
let outerLibraryResponse; // define a variable outsid elf try/catch

try {
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
  );
  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
  let options = {
    storageOptions: {
      skipBackup: true,
      path: 'images',
    },
  };

  ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
    if (response.didCancel) {
      console.log('User cancelled image picker');
    } else if (response.error) {
      console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
    } else if (response.customButton) {
      console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      alert(response.customButton);
    } else {
      libraryResponse = {
        uri: response.assets[0].uri,
        fileName: response.assets[0].fileName,
        type: response.assets[0].type,
      };

      outerLibraryResponse = libraryResponse;
    }
  });
} else {
  console.log('Library permission denied');
}
} catch (err) {
 console.log(err);
}
…
```

Comment: have already tried this form, and the final return returns first "undefined" and only then will run the try-Catch

Comment: Now I start to understand what you really want :)
You need to pass the `callBack` from the outer component.